# Typescript not getting any type information from a d.ts file for an existing js file

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I suspsect that I'm doing something wrong here but if I have the existing file `demo.js` in a Node app which contains:

```
var Demo = function () {
    let self = this;
    self.sayGoodbye = (x) => `goodbye ${x}`;
};
module.exports = new Demo();
```

I would use this in a regular js file with

```
const demo = require('./demo');
demo.sayGoodbye('foo');
```

I've written a d.ts file called `demo.d.ts` that lives next to `demo.js`

```
export = Demo
declare class Demo {
    sayGoodbye(x: string) : string
}
```

In my new typescript file `run.ts` I've written the following:

```
const dem = require('./demo');
console.log(dem.sayGoodbye('foo'));
```

When I hover over the `dem` variable (in VSCode) the type is listed as `any` and I get no type information. 
Here is my tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,          // allow sourcemap support
        "strictNullChecks": true,   // enable strict null checks as a best practice
        "module": "commonjs",            // specify module code generation,
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "target": "es2015",            // specify ECMAScript target version
        "allowJs": true,             // allow a partial TypeScript and JavaScript codebase
        "experimentalDecorators": false,
        "types" : ["node"],
        "baseUrl":"."
    },
    "include": [
        "./**/*.ts",
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

If anyone could explain where I've gone wrong with d.ts or require statement I'd appreciate it.

### Update:

I altered the d.ts file to this:

```
interface Demo {
    sayGoodbye(x: string) : string
}

declare var demo : Demo
export = demo
```

as I figured that the previous one wasn't actually representative of the file. If I understand it correctly the export of the inital one would have been a constructor function instead of an instance.
If I now change the import statement in run.js to

```
import dem = require('./demo');
console.log(dem.sayGoodbye('foo'));
```

and I now get intellisense. Unfortunately the transpiled JS now has the following line:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

It's not a deal breaker to have this present but I'd like to know how I can remove it but keep the require as the import for non-module based code.

Comment: Since you mention "hovering over", I suspect this may be an IDE-specific question. Mind telling us what your development environment is?

Comment: Updated to state that it was VS Code. Thanks